# Does lwIP support Android versions below 4.0.0

Tags: android, embedded, lwip

This is my first question.. I am working on lwIP.. I have my own AP with which i can connect my station(in this case it is my android phone). My phone gets connected to the AP but when i try to access its HTTP page on phone, it shows some connection authentication error. I have checked wireshark packets on which i can see proper tcp handshaking taking place.. But as soon as the client sends a GET packet my AP sends reset packets and no data packets are exchanged further.. Android version of my phone is 2.2.2.. Another phone with Android version 4.0.4 gets connected to this AP and I am also able to access the AP's HTTP page. Is this inbuilt of lwIP that it supports only android versions 4.0 and above???

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: What is iwip? In general you have the internet permission right?

Comment: @rekire, OP means LWIP - http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/